# Create VirtualBox package with "kmk packing" fails with Error 127

Tags: c++, makefile, virtualbox

I want to create a VirtualBox installation file(msi) from the VirtualBox binaries(that are created from building the sources).
To do this, I build the VirtualBox sources found here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Windows%20build%20instructions.
After build(kmk) i run:
"kmk packing" 

After packing for 3 minutes, i get this error:

```
D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-4.3.0/kBuild/bin/win.x86/kmk_redirect.exe -a+to D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-.3.0_1/out/win.x86/release/obj/Installer/win/NLS/License_it_IT.wxl -- D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-4.3.0/kBuild/bin/win.x86/kmk_echo.exe -n '<String Id="LicenseText">'make (e=127): The specified procedure could not be found.
kmk: *** [D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-.3.0_1/out/win.x86/release/bin/additions/VBoxWHQLFake.exe] Error 127
```

To try to fix this issue I changed a little bit the file out\win.x86\release\obj\Installer\win\NLS\License_en_US.wxl like: **< String Id="LicenseText">Test< /String>**

This seemed that somehow worked but came up to another error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-4.3.0_1/tools/win.x86/autoit/v3.2.10.0/Aut2Exe/Aut2exe.exe /in D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-4.3.0_1/src/VBox/Additions/WINNT/Installer/VBoxWHQLFake.au3 /out D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-4.3.0_1/out/win.x86/release/bin/additions/VBoxWHQLFake.exe /icon D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-4.3.0_1/src/VBox/Frontends/VirtualBox/images/OSE/VirtualBox_win.ico /comp 4 /unicode, ...) failed.
make (e=127): The specified procedure could not be found.
kmk: *** [D:/_WORK/Dale/VirtualBox-4.3.0_1/out/win.x86/release/bin/additions/VBoxWHQLFake.exe] Error 127
```

Do anybody encounter this issue, or has somebody succesfully created a Virtual Box installer from it's binaries(build from sources)?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to build VirtualBox installer on 64-bit Windows.

To fix your problem you should install http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ and set VBOX_PATH_AUTOIT3 in LocalConfig.kmk. But it's not the end of the problems...

You should also install WIX. Please note that the installation path should not contain whitespaces in it.

WIX is not enough. To build installer for guest additions you also have to install NSIS 2.46. Again, installation path must not contain any whitespaces. Additionally NSIS_CONFIG_LOG has to be defined. It is not defined by default. You need to either compile NSIS by yourself or get the the advanced logging build from http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds

Also you must install http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsProcess_plugin and http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in

Please also note if signing is enabled the kmk packing must be called from elevated (administrator) command prompt.

I also had to put mkisofs.exe in VirtualBox-source\tools\win.amd64\bin directory

Moreover, zip.exe has to be available in PATH

I also copied following files into output bin directory: QtCoreVBox4.dll, QtGuiVBox4.dll, QtNetworkVBox4.dll, QtOpenGLVBox4.dll and accessible\qtaccessiblewidgets4.dll

Windows SDK Components for Windows Installer Developers is another requirement.

My LocalConfig.kmk is as follows:

```
VBOX_SIGNING_MODE=test
PATH_TOOL_MINGW32=C:/vbox-build32/mingw32
VBOX_PATH_WIX=C:\vbox-build\WindowsInstallerXMLv3.5\bin
VBOX_PATH_AUTOIT3="C:/Program Files (x86)/AutoIt3"
#Whitespaces in NSIS path result in error
VBOX_PATH_NSIS="C:/vbox-build/NSIS"
#Quotation marks in VBOX_PATH_DIFX result in error
VBOX_PATH_DIFX=C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\redist\DIFx\DIFxAPI\$(KBUILD_TARGET_ARCH)
#Microsoft Windows SDK. Whitespaces in path result in error
VBOX_PATH_MSITRAN="C:\vbox-build\SDK\v7.1\Bin\MsiTran.Exe"
VBOX_PATH_MSIDB="C:\vbox-build\SDK\v7.1\Bin\MsiDb.Exe"
VBOX_PATH_WISUBSTG="C:\vbox-build\SDK\v7.1\Samples\sysmgmt\msi\scripts\WiSubStg.vbs"
VBOX_PATH_WISUMINFO="C:\vbox-build\SDK\v7.1\Samples\sysmgmt\msi\scripts\WiSumInf.vbs"
VBOX_WITH_WEBSERVICES=
```